# Setting videoGravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill has no effect on iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, ios5, avplayer

I have implemented a custom movie player with `AVPlayer`. On setting the value of videoGravity in `AVPlayerLayer` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` I see the desired effect in `iOS` `4.2, 4.3`. But somehow on `iOS 5.0` it has got no effect. Is anybody seeing a similar issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On iOS5 you should reset layers bounds after setting videoGravity.

This worked for me:

```
((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds;
```

**EDITED:** "self" points to a PlayerView (subclass of UIView) object from example "Putting all together":
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

Comment: what do you mean by reset? what you are doing is nothing. The two sides of the last line are equal. As expected this has no effect on iOS 8.

Comment: Yeah, in the last line of the code, LHS and RHS are the same, how is it resetting the bounds ?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution to this issue. **Tick checkbox "Clip Subviews" in IB** for the view with the layer you're going to attach the video player to. Then, set the AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill of your AVPlayerLayer object. If you don't have the view in IB but you're creating it programmatically, set its **clipsToBounds** property to YES.